# -eq operator not working as expected

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have following program

```
read CHAR
if [[ ($CHAR -eq Y) || ($CHAR -eq y) ]]
then
  echo "YES"
elif [[ ($CHAR -eq N) || ($CHAR -eq n) ]]
then
  echo "NO"
fi
```

It didn't work as expected, even though if I pass N to CHAR, it still prints YES.

When I replace the -eq with = it works as expected.

```
read CHAR
if [[ ($CHAR = Y) || ($CHAR = y) ]]
then
  echo "YES"
elif [[ ($CHAR = N) || ($CHAR = n) ]]
then
  echo "NO"
fi
```

May I know why -eq here not working as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-eq` construct is for comparing integers and *not* strings. You need the equality check operator `=` or `==` with `[[..]]` or using `=` with `[..]`

The `[..]` is guaranteed to be POSIX compliant and should work on any shell, while the `[[..]]` is a `bash`/`zsh` specific construct which provides more features to `[`. Also the `(..)` around the checks are *not* needed at all.

So purely POSIX just do

```
read char
if [ "$char" = "Y" ] || [ "$char" = "y" ]; then
    printf 'matches Yes \n'
fi
```

Also another POSIX variant would be to use a `case` statement as

```
read char
case "$char" in
    [Yy]) echo "Yes" ;;
    [Nn]) echo "No"  ;;
    *) echo "incorrect" ;;
esac
```

Comment: it's not posix, but in bash, `==` is documented to work with the `test` aka `[...]` built-in.  has done so since at least bash v3.x.  probably earlier.  also works with /usr/bin/test from GNU coreutils.

Answer (score 2):

`-eq` is a numeric comparison operator. Use `=` (either `=` or `==` with `[[ ...]]`) for strings.

You can find further detail in he documentation, `man bash`.

Another tool that may be helpful is https://shellcheck.net